# Codeigniter onclick to trigger insert function in controller

Tags: codeigniter

I'm a fresh learner in using CI, I have question on how to onclick link to call function in controller to insert into database, I found some threads that is not a proper way to call function in a view, but alternately, how can I achieve purpose like this? which is more in dynamic way.

Controller:

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller{

public function view($page='home'){

    if(!file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php')){
        show_404(); 
    }

    $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);

    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->model('getdb');

    $data['results'] = $this->getdb->getAll();

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('inc/mainmenu', $data);
    $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    //$this->insertValues();

}


function insertValues(){
    $this->load->model('getdb');

    $newRow = array(
        'name' => 'andy'
    );

    $this->getdb->insert1($newRow);
    echo "inserted!";
}

}
```

Model getdb:

```
class Getdb extends CI_Model {

function getAll(){
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM test');

    return $query->result();
}

function insert1($data){
    $this->db->insert('test', $data);
}

}
```

in View, I want to click on the link and trigger the insertValues() function,

```
<h1>Insert into DB</h1>
<p><a href="" >Insert single row</a></p>
```

please kindly advise, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Calling one controller action form another action is anti MVC. What you would like to do instead is call the `insertValues` action first (from your link), do the insertion and redirect to `view` action. It will now contain the new record.

Answer (score 0):

Consider you have the data in an array against certain names like this way.

```
$data = array(
      'x' => $a,
      'y' => $b,
      'z' => $c,
);

 The variables x,y and z all are column names which you are using in the database to insert. Those names should be same names in the table also.
```

call the model function to insert now.

```
$this->model->insert_values($data);
```

In the model file write the function to insert all the values.

```
public function insert_values($data)
 {
     $this->insert_helper('table_name',$data);
 }
```

This is a generic function to insert values.

```
public function insert_helper($table_name, $data_array){
    $this->db->insert($table_name,$data_array);
    return $this->db->insert_id();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do these answers have to do with the simple question of how to create the link?

```
<h1>Insert into DB</h1>
<p><a href="'.<?php echo base_url();?>.'pages/insertValues" >Insert single row</a></p>
```

For the record the base_url() function isn't absolutely necessary but I find it helps a lot when deep in directories. It just simplifies making sure you're going back to the right controller.

Comment: I wonder i can't call page like http://site/ci/pages/inserValues, its returned 404 Page Not Found, any idea?

Comment: is that how you've actually got it typed? If it is you may want to make it insertValues not inserValues. If the typo isn't in the code you need to check your routing, have you removed the index.php from your url's? If not just add that before the pages, so index.php/pages/insertValues

Comment: Thanks @Rick, I had found that `$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';` caused insertValues was unable to call in route.php, any cure for this issue?

Comment: $route['^(?!main).*'] = "main/$0"; That is the routing I use for my default controller, that means anything I have in the main controller can be called as www.example.com/whatever doesn't matter if the individual functions in that controller have extended functions or not. Not sure if it will help with your situation but worth a shot.